# point sampling for 1000 huge shape files without reading whole the shape file in R

Tags: r, shapefile

I am trying to compute some statistic for a lot of huge shape files (each file consist of five million features) using a points shape file in R via readOGR or other functions but the VM crash after reading a few files because of memory exhaustion of 32 GB ram!

I would be thankful if you know any solution for this issue, please inform me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try the new `sf` package:

```
install.packages('sf')
library(sf)
nc <- st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))
```

5 million features however sounds a lot. You should try splitting them up if possible.

More information on `sf` here:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/vignettes/sf1.html